# Horizontal menu Dropdown links position issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying build a horizontal menu with a drop down sub menu using CSS. I have created the menu with below code

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-menu-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://google.com">Link2</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <div class="sub-menu-bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://google.com">Sub Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://google.com">Sub Link2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-menu-bar {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.main-menu-bar > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-menu-bar > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 15%;
    min-width: 140px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.main-menu-bar > ul > li:hover .sub-menu-bar {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.sub-menu-bar {
    display: none;
    background-color: green;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sub-menu-bar > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu-bar > ul > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nalaka526/zLp1sm0f/2/)

Here my problem is, sub menu links (under Link3) are horizontally centered on the page but I want it under the parent link. But I cant get it right, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change position from `absolute` to `relative`

In `.sub-menu-bar`, Add `float:left;`

Change to this:

```
.main-menu-bar > ul > li:hover .sub-menu-bar {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zLp1sm0f/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer... can you also make the green row (sub menu) fill full page width..

Comment: Not sure if you can with the position being `relative`. If you were to increase the width you will be increasing `width` to the right leaving white space on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Change"position: absolute" in the class ".main-menu-bar> ul> li" and in the class "menu-bar-.sub> ul> li" add :

```
     clear: both; 
     float: left; 
     width: 100%; 
     text-align: center;
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLp1sm0f/7/)